# Is this approach correct for sending a request JS?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, conditional-operator

Based on boolean value condition it should send that message to backend. Currently I made it like this:

```
async submit() {
...   

 await api.submitProduct (
              productId,
              product.instock.unlimited == false ? 'book' : 'ebook'
              )
```

So it should check product's instock proper contains unlimited value which is false than it should submit 'book'  else ebook. Is this the correct approach? The question is related to the following line:

```
 product.instock.unlimited == false ? 'ebook' : 'book'
```

Comment: You need not check against true or false , if unlimited is a boolean  product.instock.unlimited ? 'ebook' : 'book' . This should work!

Comment: The point is that there is also option undefined in which case it sends book as well. That's why I check false value first.

Comment: Then I would suggest to use if-else if

Comment: To clarify, what do you want to do with values that are `undefined`? Do you want to exclude them altogether? In other words, not return either `book` or `ebook`?

Comment: @Muirik false only for book else ebook

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer below now @NewTechLover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I initially pointed out, you're using `==` which will not specifically check the type, and so items that have a value of `undefined`, which is a "falsy" value, will end up being assigned to the `book` category. That's because the double equals operator coerces the operands if their types are not the same.

Using `===` will prevent that from occurring, as only items that specifically have a boolean value of `false` will meet the test criteria. It's generally a best practice to use `===` to avoid these kinds of scenarios.

```
product.instock.unlimited === false ? 'book' : 'ebook'
```

Comment: So my solution is correct only === this should be fixed right?

Comment: If the value is undefined , it will again send book in the request . SO using if -else if is better approach. You cant handle using ternary operator

Comment: wait undefined is not getting counted as ebook since it's counting as else cases and not false right??

Comment: bad answer ever, `product.instock.unlimited === false ? 'book' : 'ebook'` do the job as well... so why so much conditions for that?.. `===` already checks the type.

Comment: Sorry, you are confused with the use of `===`... See my post (and Hassan's one) below.

Comment: I have changed this back to my original answer, once NewTechLover clarified his use case. This is what I originally posted as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the condition you need to apply.

The abstract equality operator does not enforce type checking and is therefore not a best practise. Infact, you can make do without `==` in almost any situation.

See the difference between the two equality operators on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#:%7E:text=Loose%20equality%20using%20%3D%3D,exactly%20as%20%3D%3D%3D%20performs%20it.).

In example below, if you are looking to send false when your value is infact of type boolean and false, then you can use strict equality operator

`value === false ? 'first' : 'second';`

However, if you are looking for 'second' for any falsy value then the check could easily be changed to

`value ? 'false' : 'second';`

Note that the following are all falsy values in js.

```
"" (Empty string)
0 (Number 0)
undefined
null
false
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confused with the use of `===`, this one checks the type and the value at the same time so you don't need to use a big function to check if the var is `false` or `undefined` but a right operator `===`.

```js
const test = (value) => value === false ? 'book' : 'ebook'

// test with false, return book
console.log(test(false))

// test with undefined, return ebook
console.log(test(undefined))
```